# 'Report Link' for SSRS to Read Directly From Server and Transfer Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, server, ssrs-2012, lookup

I'm currently working with Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012 and trying to figure out an SSRS-related question boss asked me.

Currently in SQL, in one server I have a Comment Table which features over 2 million records and due to restrictions on main DW, I'm not able to transfer all the data from that server into a different server where all my reporting is done from.

Using SSRS, I'm trying to see if there is a way where I can provide a 'comment lookup' link and have it launch a SSRS report that can read directly from a server and also transfer parameters?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are those linked servers? If yes, then just add server instance name, which is using four part query

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this.

**In the current report**

As @LONG said in a comment on your question, if the Sql Server with the comments is a linked server in the data warehouse Sql Server, then you could include the comments within the same report. This is like including data from another database on the same Sql Server, except you also specify the linked server name like so: `LinkedServerName.Database.Schema.TableName`.

For example, let's say the comments are on blogs:

```
SELECT B.Title, C.Comment
FROM Blogs B
INNER JOIN CommentServer.CommentsDb.dbo.Comments C ON C.BlogId = B.BlogId
```

**In a drill-down Subreport**

You can create a report which uses a datasource that accesses the Sql Server with the comments. On your main report, on the relevant cell for the field, Right-Click, select `Textbox Properties...` choose `Actions` in the left menu, select `Go To Report` and choose your comments report from the drop down. Then you are able to map the subreport's parameters to the main report's parameters and fields and these will be passed through when running the subreport.

When you click on that field when in the main report, it will automatically drill down into the comments report.

**As a parameterised link to run the report**

Again, create a report for the comments. On your main report, on the relevant cell for the field, Right-Click, select `Textbox Properties...` choose `Actions` in the left menu, select `Go To URL`. For the expression for the URL, put in something like:

```
="http://ReportServer/ReportFolder/ReportName.rdl&rs%3aCommand=Render&BlogId=" & Fields!BlogId.Value & "&FromDate=" & Parameters!FromDate.Value & "&ToDate=" & Parameters!ToDate.Value
```

This will turn the field in your report into a parameterised link to the comments report.